# How to disable link with #?

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to disable a link by putting a # for the URI. But when its clicked it goes go the index page of my appication.

Does anyone know how to go around this??

Below is the code I am using.

```
<?= anchor("#", "Set my own payment option", "id='set_payment_option'")?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using url helper already you can use `current_url()` function as well.

```
<?= anchor(current_url().'/#', 'Set my own payment option', 'id="set_payment_option"') ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace # with

```
javascript://
```

I don't try in codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid doing any server request at all to save resources. Use javascript instead

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">My disabled link</a>
```